# summernote editor not opening (laravel 5.2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, summernote

I am using summernote js in laravel 5.2.

In a form,when user clicks on edit button, summernote editor should open for the fields.Actually it was working for a single field but when i applied it for more than one field,its not working.

my view:

```
 <form action="{{route('account')}}" id="acc" class="ac" method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Estado</label>
  @foreach($accounts as $account)
  @if($user== $account->user)
  {!! $account->estado !!}



  <textarea  style="display:none;" name="textfield4" id="textfield4"></textarea>


  <div class="col-lg-2 estado " id="estado"></div>
  @endif
  @endforeach



</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-3 "><label for="textfield5">I'm Good At:</label>
  @foreach($accounts as $account)
  @if($user== $account->user)
  {!! $account->goodat !!}





   <textarea  style="display:none;" name="textfield5" id="textfield5"></textarea>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 es" id="goodat"></div>

  @endif
  @endforeach

<br /><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-info edit">Edit</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-send-message" >Save</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token">
    </div>


  </form>
```

my script:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $estado = $('#estado'); 
var $goodat = $('#goodat'); 

var edit = function() { 
$estado.summernote({focus: true}); 
$goodat.summernote({focus: true}); 
}; 

$('.edit').on('click', edit); 

$("#acc").on('submit', function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
var self = this; 

// lets check some stuff 
console.log($estado); 
console.log($estado.summernote('code')); 
console.log($('#textfield4')); 
console.log($('#textfield4').val()); 
console.log($('#textfield4').text()); 

var estado = $estado.summernote('code'); 
$("#textfield4").val(estado); //populate text area 

var goodat = $goodat.summernote('code'); 
$("#textfield5").val(goodat); //populate text area 

self.submit(); 
return false; 
});
});


</script>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I've found out that, after clicking on save button ( which results in null values in db)(everytime a user logins) , edit button starts working perfectly.

**EDIT 2:**

after placing all links and scripts in head tag ,**error:** $ is not defined .

```
     <head>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::to('src/css/crush.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::to('src/css/groups.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::to('src/css/Untitled-2.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::to('src/css/font-awesome.css')}}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::to('src/css/style.css')}}">





<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" ></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>
   <script src="/src/js/myplace.js"></script>
   <script src="{{URL::asset('src/js/script.js')}}"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: what do you mean by you applied it to more than one field?

Comment: i mean earlier i have applied it only for textfield4(it worked), now i want to apply for textfield5 too(now doesnt work for both) (as shown in view)

Comment: Ensure you edit function is called - add console.log($estado, $goodat); to your edit function and tell us the console output

Comment: getting following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $estado is not defined(…)

Comment: What is the result of $('#estado');  in your console?

Comment: Its Result is Null

Comment: Then you simply do not have the element on your screen. your loop seems to be wrong

Comment: Then why it works for single loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123163/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-frank-provost).

Comment: Have You tried to change $(document).ready(function() {}); to $(window).load(function() {});  ?

Comment: @num8er didn't worked.

Comment: Have You checked inspector panel of chrome or firebug console of firefox? any exceptions and etc?

Comment: @num8er guide me, i'll check. i am using chrome

Comment: right click on anything in page => 'inspect element' => select 'console' tab, then refresh browser You'll get js exceptions there (if they exist).

Comment: @num8er ohk ohk , no no console is showing nothing .

Comment: can You give some public url to test it live?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123636/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-num8er).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have some asynchronous issues here, since it works sometimes, and sometimes not. You are setting the value of the textareas based on the values of the summernote fields. You can't be sure though, that `$estado.summernote('code')` is already finished before using the value of the summernote field to set the value of `textfield4` (same holds for `$goodat.summernote('code')` and `textfield5`.

When you use callbacks for the summernote events, you can prevent this behaviour and have more control.

```
$('#estado').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
      console.log('onChange:', contents, $editable);
      $("#textfield4").val(contents); //populate text area
    }
  } 
});
```

Read more [here](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange)

Another thing that could be causing trouble, is the foreach loop containing elements with hardcoded id's. Since id's have to be unique this can give some unexpected results. Of course, when `$user` matches `$account->user` only once, everything is fine, but I usually don't take the risk.

UPDATE: added a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/97tet4so/6/) of a possible implementation.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/97tet4so/ with an implementation.

Comment: Why not? Do you get an error or anything? Is everything rendered in your view?

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle and activated the edit button. I hope it is the desired behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123969/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-piscator).

Answer (score 1):

You wanted multiple textareas with summernote?

Take:  (;

```js
$(function() {
  
  var $estado = $('#estado');
  var $goodat = $('#goodat');
  var isEditorsActive = false;
  function activateEditors() {
    $estado.summernote({
      focus: true
    });

    $goodat.summernote({
      focus: true
    });
    
    isEditorsActive = true;
  }
  function deactivateEditors() {
    $estado.summernote('destroy');
    $goodat.summernote('destroy');
    isEditorsActive = false;
  }
  $('button.edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    (isEditorsActive)? deactivateEditors() : activateEditors();
  });
  
  
  $("form#ac").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if(isEditorsActive) {
      var estado = $estado.summernote('code');
      var goodat = $goodat.summernote('code');
      
      $('#data-estado').html(estado);
      $('#data-goodat').html(goodat);
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>


<form action="{{route('account')}}" id="ac" class="ac" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Estado</label>
      @foreach($accounts as $account) 
      @if($user== $account->user)
      <div class="estado" id="estado" style="width:100%">
        {!! $account->estado !!}
      </div>
      @endif 
      @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>I'm Good At:</label>
      @foreach($accounts as $account) 
      @if($user==$account->user)
      <div class="goodat" id="goodat" style="width:100%">
        {!! $account->goodat !!}
      </div>
      @endif 
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save">Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default edit">Edit</button>
</form>


ESTADO:
<div id="data-estado">
</div>

GOOD AT:
<div id="data-goodat">
</div>
```

but after this You still cannot get the data that inside these textareas - so really something is wrong with Your blade template

http://num8er.me/summernote.html

Comment: actually i wanted multiple textareas on clicking edit button.

Comment: @YaShChaudhary fixed

Comment: at num8er nope :( !

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $estado.summernote is not a function

Comment: :D You even have not attached summernote.js file to template! look it works in my example, even I've not changed Your template file to make it work with blade. But You've not injected necessary for summernote files to template.

Comment: Copy whole page (not blade file, just what in source code in browser) to somewhere. Let people check Your problem.

Comment: Man, sorry, I'm out, have no time to play with newbie. Sorry.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined....its showing error at this line :$(function() {